# Grass dying where there are mower tire tracks

Tags: grass, lawn-mower

Why the grass is dying where there are mower tire tracks? Do I have some fungi problem?
[image]

Comment: Do you follow the same pattern every time you mow?

Comment: Why are there only mower tracks in that area and not anywhere else?

Comment: I doubt the mower has any connection to the dead spot in the lawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of the exact reason, but I saw this on a lawn I maintained (with a heavy mower).

What I did then was for a few months to mow an overlap of half a strip at the edge then continue as usual. This was to rest the balding patches.

I changed to continually overlapping every round so the wheels didn't  compress the same place all the time.

After about 9 months the lines disappeared.

I never had the problem with my small electric mowers.

Comment: After few days of good watering. The grass start to recover and there is no other signs of fungi issue.